# How to write this query in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-ce, subquery

I know SQL Server CE does not allow subselects that return scalar values. Is there any way how to rewrite this query so it will work? The issue is the sub-select, of course, SQL CE returns a parsing error.

```
Insert INTO InvoiceItems (InvoiceID, Item, Price, Amount, Unit) 
   SELECT 
      (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM IncomeInvoices), Item, Price, Amount, Unit 
   FROM 
      InvoiceItems 
   WHERE
      InvoiceID = @1
```

Comment: Does it give you an error?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Duplicate all records so far in the table?

Comment: what about a `join` with `having` clause?

Comment: Yes, it is part of duplication but the InvoiceID must be the newest (Max) one. The rest needs to be just duplicated. SQL CE simply says there is an error in parsing etc.